# Why doesn't my while loop go through all the cases when the conditions are true

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, do-while

I have a problem with the while loop, in png linked down below, you'll see what im trying to do.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

If the date would be 5 3 0 it shoud give back `CCCDG`. Something is wrong. I can't use `For` or `Goto` and have to use `while` or `do-while`.

```
using System;

namespace FlowChart
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string wprowadzoneLiczby = Console.ReadLine();
            int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(wprowadzoneLiczby.Split(' '), new Converter<string, int>(int.Parse)); 
                
            while (arr[0]>0)
            {
                while (arr[2]>0 && arr[0]>0)
                {
                    arr[0] -= 1;
                    arr[2] -= 1;
                    Console.Write("C");
                }
                while (arr[2]<0)
                {
                    Console.Write("D");
                    while (arr[2]>0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;
                    }
                    while (arr[2]<=0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("G");
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            while (arr[0]<0)
            {
                Console.Write("E");
                Console.Write("G");
                Console.WriteLine();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a `while` loop which has an unconditional break at the end is essentially just an `if` statement.

Comment: In your example input of `5 3 0`, `arr[2]` is going to be equal to 0. Why would any of the (inner) loops run when you have conditions requiring `arr[2]` to not be equal to 0?

Comment: It might help to read Eric Lippert's [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Okay, so i have a different question maybe a stupid one, but if the while inside the while end, it goes back to the first while or it goes forward to the next one.

Comment: I want to emphasize the importance of learning how to use the debugger. Instead of trying to guess what the program is doing you can actually follow along each step of the way. Unfortunately this is sometimes overlooked when teaching programming.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your valuable comments, it just frustrated me that I can't find a fault. I'm new here and that's it.

Comment: And I found the bug, by the way. :D

Answer (score 0):

Feels like I'm doing your homework for you :)
(but I was bored)

It's easier to follow if you use "x", "y", "z" vars rather than an array.
I'm sure there are other ways of factoring this. Especially the "z>0" part in the flow diagram. But this is "fine".

Note, in your code, that last loop might never exit as it's possible to get there with x>0 if x>y at the start.

Note, I've factored this to just take the numbers as a string. Just me being lazy and not wanting to keep entering the strings as I coded.
I'm sure you can refactor that bit as you need.

Note the `break` in order to escape that loop.

Also note that there are several ways that this can fail. ie what happens if you enter less than 3 numbers?

As the others has said...
Learn how to use the debugger to step through your code.
Learn about "unit tests". These will "assert" that you get the right output for each input. Which means that you can just "run the tests" to check which fail, rather than having to manually enter the strings over and over.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            V2("1 2 3");
            V2("-2 0 2");
            V2("1 -1 2");
            V2("2 2 0");
            V2("5 3 0");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void V2(string numbers)
        {
            Console.Write(numbers + " = ");
            string[] n = numbers.Split(' ');

            int x = int.Parse(n[0]);
            int y = int.Parse(n[1]);
            int z = int.Parse(n[2]);

            while (x > 0)
            {
                while (y > 0)
                {
                    x -= 1;
                    y -= 1;
                    Console.Write("C");
                }
                Console.Write("D");
                break;
            }
            if (x <= 0)
            {
                Console.Write("E");
            }

            if (x <= 0 || z <= 0)
            {
                Console.Write("G");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your input. While writing this code I assumed that the given data would be entered correctly, and it is important not to use arr [0] but assign to a variable. However, this is shortcode, and my main focus is to only use the while function. After a few minutes, I came to the correct solution. I did not expect someone to write something for me. This is also my first post, and I have no idea how to make a question complete. I wish everyone a good day. And my lesson from today is to learn to debbug!

Comment: No worries. We are all learning. The "homework" comment was supposed to be a joke. Probably did not translate well. So I learned something too.
None of the comments were intended as criticism. Just observations.
Glad to hear you have made progress.